# Collections.binarySearch returning negetive integers

Tags: java

The below code is not searching properly...
Please help as soon as possible..

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;

class Car{

    public int speed;

    public Car(int speed){
        this.speed = speed;
    }
}

class Compare implements Comparator<Car>{

    public int compare(Car C1, Car C2) {

        if(C1.speed < C2.speed)
            return -1;
        else
            return 1;

    }

}

public class Main{  
    public static void main(String[] args){

        Car c ;

        ArrayList<Car> a = new ArrayList<Car>();

        for(int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++){
                a.add(new Car(i));
        }

        Collections.sort(a, new Compare());

        System.out.println(Collections.binarySearch(a, new Car(0), new Compare()));

    }
}
```

I'm getting the output as some negative numbers.

Comment: Since there is no condition in your compare method that returns 0.

Comment: Yes, that was the mistake. Thank's a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comparator is incorrect. It should return 0 if the two cars have the same speed.

As coded, if A has the same speed as B, `A > B` if you use `compare(A, B)`, and `B > A` if you use `compare(B, A)`, which is a clear violation of the Comparator contract.

Since a car is never considered equal to another car by your comparator, the binarySearch never finds any car equal to to car searched, and it thus returns a negative value, as documented.